# Deserializing Streaming Data Larger Than Memory Capacity With Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the following code to decompress a local ZIP file containing a compressed Json feed retrieved by HttpClient.

```
 ProgressStream progressStream = null;
 API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject root = null;
 private void import_File(string file)
    {
        isImporting = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Importing " + Path.GetFileName(file));
        using (FileStream read = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            progressStream = new ProgressStream(read);
            using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(progressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {


                UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(zip);
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {

                    root = serializer.Deserialize<API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject>(jsonTextReader);
                    //I'd like to manipulate root between these lines
                    foreach (API_Json_Special_Feeds.Item item in root.items)
                    {
                        Special_Feed_Data.special_Feed_Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                progressStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
 }
```

The file is rather large at 300-600MB compressed and 9-11GB uncompressed. As you can see, I inserted an intermediate stream so I can check for throughput. It all works great on my 64GB machine, but the client only has 8GB to play with. Attempting to decompress and serialize 9-11G on a machine with 8G of RAM is not going to be fun.

I'm new to Json, so my original thought was to put some sort of filter or pagination on the data as it's being deserialized, maybe in the same method I use to measure stream throughput:

```
  private void timer()
    {
        bool isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning)
        {
            if (progressStream != null)
            {
                kBytes_Read = ((double)progressStream.BytesRead / (double)1024);
                mem_Used = get_Memory_Used();
                if (root != null)
                   Console.WriteLine("Root contains " + root.items.Count.ToString() + " items");
                //This doesn't work, because root is null until ALL of the data is deserialized
            }
            Thread.Sleep(450);
        }
    }
```

In my head, I see Json.net deserialzing one record at a time and adding it to the list of items in root. The trouble with this is that "root" evaluates to null until the stream is complete - I can't find a way of accessing the deserialized data until the deserialize method has completed.

**Question** Is there any way to access the data that's already been serialized to Root.Items while deserialization is still in-progress? If not, how would one go about halting/paginating/pausing deserialization of large data so it doesn't blow out memory?

I thank you for your time and in advance for any thoughts or suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to avoid deserializing whole root object into memory. You can do this using the same `JsonTextReader`, because it parses json tokens one by one, but you have to do some minor manual parsing. Here is an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // our fake huge object
        var json = @"{""root"":{""items"":[{""data"":""value""},{""data"":""value""}]}}";
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json))) {
            bool insideItems = false;
            while (reader.Read()) {
                // reading tokens one by one
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName) {
                    // remember, this is just an example, so it's quite crude
                    if ((string) reader.Value == "items") {
                        // we reached property named "items" of some object. We assume this is "items" of our root object
                        insideItems = true;
                    }
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject && insideItems) {
                    // if we reached start of some json object, and we have already reached "items" property before - we assume
                    // we are inside "items" array
                    // here, deserialize items one by one. This way you will consume almost no memory at any given time
                    var item = JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<DataItem>(reader);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Data);
                }                    
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataItem {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Remember, this is just example. In real life case you need to do more careful manual parsing (check if "items" property is indeed of your root object, check if it's an array and so on), but general idea is the same.

Comment: Much obliged, Evk! In my case, the files (there are many) are compressed. In order to implement this, then, I'd have to forego streaming, decompress each file locally, and then read with textreader? Please have patience with my ignorance. I'm sure you know how it is when you put your foot into a new tech for the first time.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger you can use the JsonTextReader with any TextReader, such as the [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader)

Comment: No no wait nevermind - I think I get what you're saying. Rather than use deserialize, I can implement the string filtering as you suggested. Awesome. Let me try to implement.

Comment: Nope, you can do exactly as you do now. Notice that you unzip also in streamed manner, so it should not unzip all in memory. Do as you do, but do not deserialize whole root object from JsonTextReader

Comment: Trouble is, the first record has the array indicator {"items":[ but there is no closing bracket until EOF. I can't seem to deserialize the first record because it contains {"items":[ and the other records don't. I thought saving a collection of values and dumping them to a deserializer, but it won't take that form of input. the jasonTextReader doesn't have the manipulation methods a normal textreader does, so I can't peek and manipulate string values.

Comment: Format is {"items":[ {"itemId" : 12321374,"parentItemId" : 12321374},{"itemId" : 12321374,"parentItemId" : 12321374}] and deserializes into a List of items. I figured you wanted me to deserialize to "Item" instead of "root" (a list of Items), but Item doesn't contain "Items" and "Root" wants an "items:[" and "]"

Comment: If I could prepend each record with "Items:[" and append it with "]" I could successfully deserialize as a single item list, but I can't manipulate the text.

Comment: Your format looks exactly like in my example code, so not sure what's the problem. Deserialize items in array one by one, not array itself.